# document.objSecuBSP.OpenDevice biometrics issues

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sdk

My problem is we have buy an finger print device on secugen but the problem occurs when i use there code , i have installed all their drives. on the html side there is this code which encounters "document.objSecuBSP.OpenDevice is not a function".

I found this [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1291029.aspx?document%20form1%20submit%20Microsoft%20JScript%20runtime%20error%20Object%20doesn%20t%20support%20this%20property%20or%20method) but its not working.

here is a sneak peak of the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example of SecuGen SecuBSP SDK Pro COM Module</title>
</head>

<script lang=javascript>
<!--
function fnRegister()
{   
    var err, payload

    try // Exception handling
    {
        // Open device. [AUTO_DETECT]
        // You must open device before enrollment.
        DEVICE_FDP02        = 1;
        DEVICE_FDU02        = 2;
        DEVICE_FDU03        = 3;
        DEVICE_FDU04        = 4;
        DEVICE_FDU05        = 5;    // HU20
        DEVICE_AUTO_DETECT  = 255;

        document.objSecuBSP.OpenDevice(DEVICE_AUTO_DETECT);
        err = document.objSecuBSP.ErrorCode;    // Get error code
    alert(err+'s');
        if ( err != 0 )     // Device open failed
        {
            alert('Device open failed !');
            return;
        }

        // Enroll user's fingerprint.
        document.objSecuBSP.Enroll(payload);
        err = document.objSecuBSP.ErrorCode;    // Get error code

        if ( err != 0 )     // Enroll failed
        {
            alert('Registration failed ! Error Number : [' + err + ']');
            return;
        }
        else    // Enroll success
        {
            // Get text encoded FIR data from SecuBSP module.
            document.bspmain.template1.value = document.objSecuBSP.FIRTextData;
            alert('Registration success !');
        }

        // Close device. [AUTO_DETECT]
        document.objSecuBSP.CloseDevice(DEVICE_AUTO_DETECT);

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    return;
}

function fnCapture()
{   
    var err

    try // Exception handling
    {
        // Open device. [AUTO_DETECT]
        // You must open device before capture.
        DEVICE_FDP02        = 1;
        DEVICE_FDU02        = 2;
        DEVICE_FDU03        = 3;
        DEVICE_FDU04        = 4;
        DEVICE_FDU05        = 5;        // HU20

        DEVICE_AUTO_DETECT  = 255;

        document.objSecuBSP.OpenDevice(DEVICE_AUTO_DETECT);
        err = document.objSecuBSP.ErrorCode;    // Get error code

        if ( err != 0 )     // Device open failed
        {
            alert('Device open failed !');
            return;
        }

        // Enroll user's fingerprint.
        document.objSecuBSP.Capture();
        err = document.objSecuBSP.ErrorCode;    // Get error code

        if ( err != 0 )     // Enroll failed
        {
            alert('Capture failed ! Error Number : [' + err + ']');
            return;
        }
        else    // Capture success
        {
            // Get text encoded FIR data from SecuBSP module.
            document.bspmain.template2.value = document.objSecuBSP.FIRTextData;
            alert('Capture success !');
        }

        // Close device. [AUTO_DETECT]
        document.objSecuBSP.CloseDevice(DEVICE_AUTO_DETECT);

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    return;
}

function fnVerify()
{   
    var err
    var str1 = document.bspmain.template1.value;
    var str2 = document.bspmain.template2.value;

    try // Exception handling
    {
        // Verify fingerprint.
        document.objSecuBSP.VerifyMatch(str1, str2);
        err = document.objSecuBSP.ErrorCode;

        if ( err != 0 )
        {
            alert('Verification error ! Error Number : [' + err + ']');
        }
        else
        {
            if ( document.objSecuBSP.IsMatched == 0 )
                alert('Verification failed !');
            else
                alert('Verification success !');
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    return;
}
// -->

</script>

<body>
<h4><b>Example of SecuGen SecuBSP SDK Pro COM Module</b></h4>
<p></p>

<form name=bspmain>

<input type=button name=btnRegister value='Register' OnClick='fnRegister();' style='width:100px'>
<br>
<input type=text name=template1 style='width:500px'>
<br>
<br>
<input type=button name=btnCapture value='Capture' OnClick='fnCapture();' style='width:100px'>
<br>
<input type=text name=template2 style='width:500px'>
<br>
<br>
<input type=button name=btnVerify value='Verify' OnClick='fnVerify();' style='width:100px'>
</form>

<OBJECT id=objSecuBSP style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" height=0 width=0 
    classid="CLSID:6283f7ea-608c-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66" 
    name=objSecuBSP VIEWASTEXT>
</OBJECT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you could try explicitly setting `document.objSecuBSP = document.getElementById("objSecuBSP");` at the very top of your `try {` block.

Comment: thanks Dereleased but no avail on this i'll start up a bounty maybe

Comment: i added bounty hoping someone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

To enable biometric verification in browser, you need to download SDK from official website: http://www.secugen.com/download/sdkrequest.htm

The Manual of SecuBSP SDK Pro says (See [SecuBSP SDK Pro Manual.PDF](ftp://202.62.69.213/Software/thumb/SecuBSP%20SDK%20Pro%20for%20Windows%20v1.49/Documents/SecuBSP%20SDK%20Pro%20Manual%20(Windows)%20SG1-0020B-006.pdf))
that you need to install 2 DLL files on your machine:
    **SecuBSPMx.DLL** and **SecuBSPMxCOM.DLL**

First Dll is mainmodule, while second is COM module, makes available to connect fingerreader device from browser.

I highly recommend to you to read the Chapter 5. Chapter. SecuBSP COM Programming in ASP (at page #47) on PDF manual above as a documentation.
[image]

Comment: hi @ahmetson thanks for the reply i have the SecuBSPMx.dll and seccuBSPMXCOM.dll  on my pc its on the system32 its still not working i have also copy the dll to the programfiles on secugen just to make sure and also delete it when its not working, currently i'm stock on this please help

Comment: It works only in IE. In Chrome or Firefox it's not work. Did you know it?

Comment: i have used the old IE but it doesnt work i'm using ie 11 , 10, 8 but its not working sorry. it must be something for what i did ? or should i not put the dll from system32 ? dont know where can i shade some light

Comment: If that's a COM dll you might need to register it with `regsvr32`

Comment: @madebydavid how do you register it on regsvr32? please enlighten me

Comment: @MaryDaisySanchez - regsvr32 is a windows tool which registers the details of a DLL into the windows registry. The DLL can then be referenced by applications using their Class ID (as seen in your `object` tag). You may need to run it for both DLLs. This can be done by running `regsvr32 C:\Path\To\My\File.DLL`